# There is something I can't understand in the code of the map function of Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is something I don't understand in the code below. That's where map (c => c).

I don't think I need to process map (c => c), is there any reason?

```js
sortedArray() {
  return somearray
       .map(c => c)
       .sort((x, y) => this.otherSortMethod(x, y));
}

otherSortMethod(x, y) {
      if (
        `${x.date} ${x.time}` ===
        `${y.date} ${y.time}`
      )
        return 0;
      if (
        `${x.date} ${x.time}` >
        `${y.date} ${y.time}`
      )
        return 1;
      return -1;
    }
```

Comment: It's making a copy of the array before sorting. However, the usual way to make a copy is to use `arr.slice()`

Answer (score 1):

`somearray.map()` function will return a new array(cloned).

`somearray.sort()` function will sort your existing array(mutate).

so if you directly use `somearray.sort((x, y) => this.otherSortMethod(x, y));` you are mutating/modifying an existing array. which can leads to side effects. As you don't hold any reference/copy of the original array.

when you use `somearray.map().sort()` you will have a **new cloned,sorted + original** array.

edits:

You are not doing anything in the map callback function so it will return an element as it is. Below is the equivalent code of the same.

```js
sortedArray() {
 let sortedArray = [...somearray]
 sortedArray.sort((x, y) => this.otherSortMethod(x, y));
 return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, the `Array.map()` function returns a new array after your operation in the callback is done on each element in the original array (full docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In your example, you are simply returning each original element (without applying any operation on it) in the callback of `.map()`, hence, returning a copy of the original array when `.map()` finishes iterating.